# SVG Image object created from javascript is not rendered

Tags: javascript, image, dom, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to create an image with a clip-path, but when the object is created dynamically, the image is not rendered.

Here is the code sample, the first SVG is created from JS and the second from Javascript.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="parent"></svg>
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <clippath id="cut-off-bottom">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" />
    </clippath>
    <image id="imgs" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473042904451-00171c69419d?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1375&q=80" clip-path="url(#clip)"></image>
</svg>
```

And JS:

```
var _svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

var clippath = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'clipPath');
clippath.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'clip');
parent.appendChild(clippath);

var rect = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'rect');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '0');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '0');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '200');
rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '200');
clippath.appendChild(rect);


var imageElement = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'image');
imageElement.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473042904451-00171c69419d?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1375&q=80');
imageElement.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');
parent.appendChild(imageElement);
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/n8pzo52q/

Comment: Why are you using setAttributeNS?

Comment: And why are you not when you have to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have all your setAttribute/setAttributeNS calls mixed up.

- setAttribute sets attributes in the null namespace so you don't need setAttributeNS for that use case.
- if you have an attribute that isn't in the null namespace such as xlink:href then you must use setAttributeNS.

```js
var _svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

var clippath = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'clipPath');
clippath.setAttribute('id', 'clip');
parent.appendChild(clippath);

var rect = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'rect');
rect.setAttribute('x', '0');
rect.setAttribute('y', '0');
rect.setAttribute('width', '200');
rect.setAttribute('height', '200');
clippath.appendChild(rect);


var imageElement = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'image');
imageElement.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473042904451-00171c69419d?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1375&q=80');
imageElement.setAttribute('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');
parent.appendChild(imageElement);
```

```html
<svg id="parent"></svg>
```

Comment: God, I'm blind. Thanks for help